# Como comparar os elementos de uma lista

Tags: python

Então, to precisando desenvolver o corpo de um codigo que percorre uma lista ja ordenada para descobrir em quais posições estao os elementos iguais. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o código abaixo possa te ajudar. Basicamente ele faz uma iteração item a item na lista e identifica se o item em uma determinada posição é igual ao anterior, já que você disse que a sua lista já está ordenada

```
lista1 = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,7,8,9,10]

prev_item = lista1[0]-1 # garante que prev_item está fora da lista1

for index in range(0,len(lista1)):
    if lista1[index] == prev_item:
        print(f'valor repetido na posição {index}')
    
    prev_item = lista1[index]
```

resultado:

```
valor repetido na posição 2
valor repetido na posição 7
valor repetido na posição 8
valor repetido na posição 9
```

Comment: tem a possibilidade de utilizar um dicionário, retornando depois cada posição para cada item procurado.

Comment: Vou tentar com esse ai! Mas esqueci de mencionar tbm que nao tenho acesso aos elementos da lista, a priori (pode modificar de acordo com quem digita). Posso seguir nesse mesmo esquema?

Comment: mesmo não tenho acessa à lista em si, a parte do `for` pra frente deve funcionar, desde que você consiga importar a lista no seu código.